# Next.js "use client" not working properly with next router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my Next.js application, I have a page.tsx file located in a [id] folder. I'm encountering following error when trying to destructure the params object as undefined.

Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'params' of 'param' as it is undefined.

This issue occurs when using the "use client" functionality. However, if I refresh the page without accessing it from another page, the error no longer occurs.

How can I resolve this error and successfully access the params object in my code?

Additionally, I'm using the following code to access the element:

```
return <Link href={`data/${_id}`}><p>{name}</p></Link>;
```

Whole code:

in folder "data"

```
export default async function DataPage() {
  const datas = await getData();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Items</h1>
      {datas?.map((data) => (
        <Data key={data._id} data={data} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
} 

function Data({ data }: any) {
  const { _id, link, name, date } = data|| {};
  return <Link href={`data/${_id}`}><p>{name}</p></Link>;
}
```

in folder "data/[id]"

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";

export default async function DataPage({ params }: any) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(params);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Data</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: components in `page.ts` accept `searchParams` not `params`